# CakePHP sort of global variable

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem with my cakePHP app. I have many Matches (each one has date field), and the problem I have is to make one Match date (the first one, concerning their dates) available everywhere in the app (especially I want to use it in default layout file).

I have tried using:

```
Configure::write('date',$match['date'])
```

But it seems to remember setted date only right after it's setted (when I proceed to the next page, `Configure::read('date')` returns `null`).

What would be the best solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply write it to the current logged in users session data?

The Configure class wont store it persistent except you write the config file and load it. But I would not do it this way for what you try to do because its inefficient and would conflict with other users except you store it for each user in a separate config key.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, I was not aware of possibility to store various data in session data, that solves my problem.